# Apache Camel: async operation and backpressure

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-camel

In Apache Camel 2.19.0, I want to produce messages and consume the result asynchronously on a concurrent seda queue while at the same time blocking if the executors on the seda queue are full.
The use case behind it: I need to process large files with many lines and need to create batches for it because a single message for each individual line is too much overhead, whereas I cannot fit the entire file into heap. But in the end, I need to know whether all batches I triggered have completed successfully.
So effectively, I need a back pressure mechanism to spam the queue while at the same time want to leverage multi-threaded processing.

Here is a quick example in Camel and Spring. The route I configured:

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AsyncCamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    public static final String ENDPOINT = "seda:async-queue?concurrentConsumers=2&size=2&blockWhenFull=true";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(ENDPOINT)
                .process(exchange -> {
                    System.out.println("Processing message " + (String)exchange.getIn().getBody());
                    Thread.sleep(10_000);
                });
    }
}
```

The producer looks like this:

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

@Component
public class AsyncProducer {

    public static final int MAX_MESSAGES = 100;

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) throws Exception {
        new Thread(() -> {
            // Just wait a bit so everything is initialized
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5_000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<CompletableFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();

            System.out.println("Producing messages");
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MESSAGES; i++) {
                CompletableFuture future = producerTemplate.asyncRequestBody(AsyncCamelRoute.ENDPOINT, String.valueOf(i));
                futures.add(future);
            }
            System.out.println("All messages produced");

            System.out.println("Waiting for subtasks to finish");
            futures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
            System.out.println("Subtasks finished");
        }).start();

    }
}
```

The output of this code looks like:

```
Producing messages
All messages produced
Waiting for subtasks to finish
Processing message 6
Processing message 1
Processing message 2
Processing message 5
Processing message 8
Processing message 7
Processing message 9
...
Subtasks finished
```

So it seems that blockIfFull is ignored and all messages are created and put onto the queue prior to processing.

Is there any way to create messages so that I can use async processing in camel while at the same time making sure that putting elements onto the queue will block if there are too many unprocessed elements?

Comment: Can you try `requestBody(..)` instead of `asyncRequestBody(..)`? It might be you end up with lots of blocked threads in a pool used to do the asynchronous message sending. Instead of blocking your client thread.

Comment: Hi @Ralf, I don't quite understand your approach - requestBody leaves the client (producer) blocking until the Consumer is finished. While I want to block the client if it is spamming the consumers, it should create messages as long as there are consumers. I solved it using a different approach, however.

Comment: That's correct. But if you do anything async then another thread is doing the work of submitting to seda and waiting for the response. The thread you run your loop in and call `asyncRequestBody(..)` won't be blocked unless the thread pool handling the async task is exhausted. But if threads get created as needed in the pool, then you will never see your looping thread being blocked.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I was kind of hoping that there is functionality that I overlooked which behaves similar to using a plain Java ExecutorService. Meaning that the producer can essentially put tasks onto the ExecutorService until the underlying queue is full, and then block until there is space availabe again. But from your explanation it seems that there are just the synchronous and async possiblity which both behave differently than I intend. But as stated, I now solved the problem as described in my own answer and this seems to work as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using streaming and a custom splitter. By doing this, I can split the source lines into chunks using an iterator that returns a list of lines instead of a single line only. With this, it seems to me that I can use Camel as required.

So the route contains the following portion:

```
.split().method(new SplitterBean(), "splitBody").streaming().parallelProcessing().executorService(customExecutorService)
```

With a custom-made splitter with the behavior as above.